# jquery: bookmarking Paragraph function, is checking for class on every single Paragraph hover efficient? is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hover

Im creating a feature using jquery on my site that allows people to place a bookmark on a paragraph when they're viewing an article, so if they want to come back later, they'll know where they stopped.

When the user clicks on "PLACE A BOOKMARK", it adds the class `.placing` to that link. When the user hovers over a paragraph, the script checks to see if the link has the `.placing` class, if it does, it fades in a div on hover that says "bookmark this paragraph", on hover off it fades that div back out.

Right now my code is placed within a `$('P').click(function...` that is within the hover function, it's caused links on the page to not fire their hover animation. So links inside paragraphs wont animate on hover because when i hover over a paragraph it's checking for the `.placing` class and doing the bookmark hover function.

How would i get the hover animation to work again on links that exist within paragraphs?
and is this the best way to do it? to check for the `.placing` class every single time i hover over a paragraph? There's gotta be a better way to do this, like a switch that only allows the bookmark paragraph hovering function to work when the switch is on, and not checking with every single paragraph hover.

```
    $('#placeBookmark').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('placing')

    })

    $('p').hoverIntent(function () {
        // HOVER ON
        if ($('#placeBookmark').hasClass('placing')) {
            $(this).append('<span id="bookmarkThis">BOOKMARK THIS</span>')
            $(this).find('#bookmarkThis').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 400) 

  $('p').click(function (e) {
        var newbm = $('#bookmark').offset().top
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var top = offset.top
        var phrases = ["SUCCESS", "SWEEEEEEET MANNN", "AWESOMELY AWESOME", "NEAT-OH!", "EXCELLENT, BOOKMARK PLACED", "BOOKMARK SAVED", "YOU DID IT KID!", "WOOOHOOO", "YOU ARE WONDERFUL"];

        if ($('#placeBookmark').hasClass('placing')) {
           //$('#placeBookmark').trigger('click')
           $('#placeBookmark').removeClass('placing')

            if (top == newbm) {
               // bookmarkColorDelay = 2000
                $('#bookmarkThis').html('<span>ITS ALREADY BOOKMARKED</span> SILLY PERSON').delay(2000).fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $(this).remove()//html('BOOKMARK THIS')
                })
            } else {
               // bookmarkColorDelay = 1000
                var selectedPhrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
                $('#bookmarkThis').html(selectedPhrase).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $(this).remove()//html('BOOKMARK THIS')
                })
                $('#bookmark').fadeOut(300, function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        left: offset.left - 30,
                        top: top
                    }).fadeIn(300);
                })
            }
            $(this).stop().delay(bookmarkColorDelay).animate({
                color: "#333",
                backgroundColor: "#fff"
            }, 200)
        }
    });

        } 
    }, function () {
        // HOVER OFF
        if ($('#placeBookmark').hasClass('placing')) {
            $(this).find('#bookmarkThis').stop().fadeOut(400, function(){
                $(this).remove()
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class selector! :-)

```
$('.placing').live('click', function(event) {
    // Whatever you want to do
});

$('.placing').live('hover', function(event) {
    // Whatever you want to do
});
```

It will work even though the class `.placing` is added later.

Comment: So, with your code, it would not be checking for `.placing` when a paragraph is hovered until the click event above is activated? I basically just don't want it to be checking for the `.placing` class unless '#placeBookmark' has been clicked(activating the "place your bookmark by clicking on a paragraph" mode)

Comment: ohh, wait, so -- instead of applying the class `.placing` to the link that activates "bookmark mode", I should apply the class `.placing` to every paragraph that could be bookmarked? Is that efficient to add a class to 20(more or less) paragraphs? And curious, do you think i should be using `event` in my example? do you see some way of using it that would be good?

Comment: You will still apply the class placing by the click on `#placeBookmark`. The code I show only controls what happens when you hover or click something with class `.placing`. It is up to you to add this class, as you do in the first few lines of your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the code by Andrea and optimise it slightly as

```
$('p.placing').live('click', function(event) {
    // Whatever you want to do
});

$('p.placing').live('hover', function(event) {
    // Whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: You are probably deoptimizing it!!!! I don't know the internals of sizzle, but most browsers support `getElementByClassName`, and most CSS parsers work from the right. This means that **probably** your code does the following: first, find all elements with class `placing`, and then filter them to find the paragraphs.